# Can't get pchar from Delphi 2007 DLL to Visual Basisc application (got garbage)

Tags: vb.net, delphi, dll, pinvoke

**VB code**

I have DLL function decalration in my VB application code:

```
Declare Function TstCharReturn Lib "myLib" Alias "TstCharReturn" (ByVal c As System.Text.StringBuilder) As Boolean
```

This is code that calls that function

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s As String
    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    r = TstCharReturn(builder)
    LogIt(s)
    LogIt(r)
End Sub
```

I got recomendation to use `StringBuilder` instead of string because `String` is immutable, but both works the same way.

**Delphi Dll code:**

```
Function TstCharReturn  (var c: pchar) : Boolean; stdcall;
var
 BuffSize: Integer;
 sOut: string;
begin

  sOut:='abcdefghijklmnoprst';
  BuffSize:=SizeOf(Char)*(Length(sOut)+1);
  getmem(c, BuffSize);
  FillChar(c^,BuffSize,0);
  Result := Length(sOut)>0;

  if Result then
  begin
    Move(sOut[1], PChar(c)^, BuffSize);
  end;

end;
```

I got garbage in VB output. What is a problem? 
And one more question. If I used `GetMem`, must I free memory somewhere or VB will do that? Is there any difference between VB6 and VB2010, because I need my dll to work with both?

Answer (score 0):

Your delphi procedure is wrong. You must not allocate new memory for the returned string, you already have a pointer to it passed in `c`, and you must fill starting from that pointer. You will need to introduce another parameter to pass the size of that buffer.

So you will have:

```
Declare Function TstCharReturn Lib "myLib" Alias "TstCharReturn" _
     (ByVal c As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
      ByVal cchSize As Integer) As Boolean
```

And:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(50) 'Buffer capacity: 50
TstCharReturn(sb, sb.Capacity)
```

Don't think that StringBuilder will be magically passed to unmanaged code as something that can accept arbitrary amount of data. You need to ensure initial capacity, which is the size available for the procedure.

Comment: The Delphi code also needs to be changed to pass the PChar, i.e. char*, by value and not by var.

Comment: You also need to tell PInvoke to marshal the `StringBuilder` as Ansi and not as Unicode, either by using the `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)` attribute on the parameter, or by setting the `Charset` property of DLLImport to `Charset.Ansi`.

Comment: @Remy Default charset for p/invoke is `Charset.Ansi`, certainly that's true in C# and I see no reason for it not to be in VB.net. Or am I wrong?

Comment: After clear GSerg description code looks more simple, but I still got crash. After change recommended by David code works perfect (remove var from delphi function declaration) - but I still have question "why?". What is changed except allowing to write to pchar memory area? Would you point me to some kind of resource to understand those things more clear.

Comment: "Default charset for p/invoke is Charset.Ansi" - looks it is true.

Comment: @user1501700 Delphi procedure with `var` expects `pointer to pointer to char`, VB declaration describes `pointer to char`. These need to match. By removing `var` you make the procedure to expect `pointer to char`. As of a resource, I would recommend any manual that nicely explains "[pointers in C++](https://www.google.ru/search?q=pointers+in+c%2B%2B&)".

Comment: Yes, that's right. `var c: PChar` has double indirection, one level of indirection to many.

Comment: The default PInvoke charset used for a string parameter in a DLL function is actually platform-specific, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx). It could be either Ansi or Unicode. Since the actual DLL parameter is only Ansi, the PInvoke code should be explicit about that to avoid any accidental mismatch.